# Use delete field along with deleted_at field in eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a legacy database that´s using **delete** 1/0 for soft delete instead of **deleted_at**
is it possible to use a deleted field name at the model level? so I can still rely on deleted_at automatically but also don´t show those old records without **deleted_at** but with **deleted** = 1 as the indication that the record is soft deleted?

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'users';
    //protected consider deleted=1 as deleted

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $user = new User;
        $user->save();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have given it a try, and created a Trait as follows:

```
namespace App\Traits;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

trait MySoftDeletes
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected function runSoftDelete()
    {
        $query = $this->newQueryWithoutScopes()->where($this->getKeyName(), $this->getKey());

        $time = $this->freshTimestamp();

        $columns = [$this->getDeletedAtColumn() => 1];

        $this->{$this->getDeletedAtColumn()} = 1;

        if ($this->timestamps && ! is_null($this->getUpdatedAtColumn())) {
            $this->{$this->getUpdatedAtColumn()} = $time;

            $columns[$this->getUpdatedAtColumn()] = $this->fromDateTime($time);
        }

        $query->update($columns);
    }
}
```

... and that seems to work just fine and updates the is_deleted column and sets it to 1 instead of a timestamp.

However, taking into account that is_deleted can also be 0 (not null), those are considered deleted. Do you know if it is possible to change that default where check and have it check where is_deleted null OR is_deleted = 0?

or use https://github.com/tenantcloud/laravel-boolean-softdeletes

Comment: I don’t want to change the deleted_at that’s fine I’m looking that maybe automatically add “AND deleted = 0” to every single query?